# Why is my function returning the wrong data type?

Tags: python

I'm making a very simple blackjack game in python and learning things as i go along and make it. The function which determines the value of the card returns a 'none' value when it should be returning integer 10 or 11 which creates an error when determining the score of the player as you cant add an integer and null together. You can see below what the code looks like:

```
        
import random
from random import randint
stacksize = 100
pScore = 0
dScore = 0
dd = 0
def card_deck():
    values = ['Ace', 'King', 'Queen', 'Jack', '10', '9', '8', '7', '6', '5', '4', '3', '2']
    suits = ['Hearts', 'Spades', 'Diamonds', 'Clubs']
    deck = []
    for i in suits:
        for x in values:
            deck.append(x + ' of ' + i)
    return deck

cards = card_deck()

def card_value(card):
    if card[:1] in ['King', 'Queen', 'Jack']:
        return int(10)
    elif card[:1] in ['10', '9', '8', '7', '6', '5', '4', '3', '2']:
        return int(card[:1])
    elif card[:1] == 'Ace':
        return int(11)
#king queen jack or ace returns value of none
```

Answer (score 1):

Couple of problems I can see off the bat.

The string of the card value will be something like "King of Hearts"

The slicing you are doing will cut that string down to "K" which will not match "King".

The numbers will match because "2 of Hearts" will be truncated to "2". However you are likely to have a problem with the number 10.

```
def card_value(card):
    card_parts = card.split(' ')
    if card_parts[0] in ['King', 'Queen', 'Jack']:
        return int(10)
    elif card_parts[0] in ['10', '9', '8', '7', '6', '5', '4', '3', '2']:
        return int(card_parts[0])
    elif card_parts[0] == 'Ace':
        return int(11)
```

Comment: Thankyou so much. I didnt fully understand what the [:1] was doing, i only just started learning python yesterday so at the moment im just doing trial and error combined with vague google searches to figure out the syntax.

Comment: Also look at random.sample() for selecting the cards